# Django migration is creating extra table

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models, migrate

I am beginner for Django and i am working on my final year project but i am stuck at one thing.

here is my model.py

```
class MatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    matches = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="matches")

    class Meta:
        app_label = "matchsystem"
```

Also my here is my migration file as well.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MatchRequest',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('times_tamp', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('receiver', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='receiver', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('sender', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='sender', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MatchList',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('matches', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='matches', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='user', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

but when i migrate the data it create an extra table with added name.

[image: I want the first table but it doesnt have the correct columns]

Any response is much appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. In database terms a `ManyToManyField` is just an extra intermediate table which has foreign keys to the two related tables. This is because you really cannot have multiple values in the same column pointing to multiple entries.

Your first table `matchsystem_matchlist` you show in the image has the fields `id` and `user_id` which is correct, `id` is the primary key and `user_id` is the foreign key (in your model `user`). This is the table for your model `MatchList`.

Next your second table `matchsystem_matchlist_matches` has the fields `id` which is the primary key, `matchlist_id` which is the foreign key to `MatchList` and `users_id` which is the foreign key to the user model. This second table is the intermediate table made for the `ManyToManyField` named `matches` in your model `MatchList`.